# Explanation on these mathematical expressions

Tags: python

Can someone explain why the following answers are possible.

1. ```
   >>> 2++2 
   4
   ```
2. ```
   >>> 2--2
   4
   ```
3. ```
   >>> 2+-2
   0
   ```

Comment: What other results were you expecting and why?

Comment: For example 1+2 = 3. But how do the above conflict with the same applied logic?

Answer (score 2):

In all the above expressions, the first operator is a binary operator, and the second operator (+ or -) is an unary operator.
So, `2++2 == 2 + (+2)`, which is equal to `2 + 2`, which is equal to `4`
similarly, `2--2` can be written as `2 - (-2)`, which is equal to `2 + 2` which is also equal to `4`.
In case of `2 + (-2)`, the expression evaluates to `2 - 2`, which is equal to `0`.

Comment: Thanks. This is educational and direct

Comment: @Ola-GoldTechnologies  If it helped you then you should consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a few spaces and it will be clear.

```
2       +         +2
2       -         -2
2       +         -2
```

Note that the first two couldn't be auto increment or decrement as there would be no operator to apply to the values.